# jQuery - multiple animations on a page

Tags: jquery, transition

I have one menu with animated dropdown subnavigation (slidedown). On the same page I have a photoslider (just beneath the navigation).

In IE I have huge hickups while I navigate through the navigation, while the photoslider is sliding. It seems like IE can't handle both transition at once.

How can I fix this 'multiple animations on a page' problem?

Comment: Please provide a link with an example to the problem so we can diagnose what is going on.

Comment: This is the website which I'm talking about: http://www.beurshalhaaglanden.nl/site/nl/beurshalhaaglanden

Comment: Is there anyone out there who can help me? I'm still stuck with it. I can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer does an awful job of caching and displaying background images (specifically repeated background images) during animation – basically, for each frame of animation, I.E. loads, places, and renders each instance of a repeating background image. [(Source of this information)](http://codegarage.com/blog/2009/09/fixing-slow-jquery-animations-in-internet-explorer/)

IE's JavaScript rendering engine is seriously lacking. There isn't a whole lot you can do besides work on optimizing images (or replacing them with CSS), and reducing the amount of animations it has to process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm now testing these things out:  - bigger image for repeatable elements  - fixed height/width for the same elements  - PNG without transparent alpha